# Bluetooth file sharing in iPhone/iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, bluetooth, mfi

As far as I know, Apple does not allow bluetooth file sharing in iPhone/iPad.

Is there any way to write a code in Objective-C to make an application to share files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to communicate between other iOS devices, Apple provides a high-level GameKit framework to make it easier to handle Bluetooth communication, which should allow you to share file data. Here's a tutorial I found: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/2

I’m not sure, but I think Apple only allow members of the Made for iPod program to access the low-level raw bluetooth APIs, and even then, can only with certified external devices.
http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

If you want a simple way to share files and other data between devices of other platforms, you might want to have a look at the Bump API: http://bu.mp/api

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I get that, using the GameKit Framework, I can connect to other iOS device via bluetooth and send some data. But shall I be able to send files ? How can I show the file structure to the user to select file to send ?